# How do I refer specifically to "this" instance of a class instead of another instance which is one of the parameters of the method?

Tags: c++, code-documentation

I wasn't sure if this question should go here or somewhere else.

I'm trying to document my C++ code but I'm having trouble describing things without being verbose.

So let's say I have a class **Number**

```
class Number {
private:
   int data;
public:
   int subtract(Number inNumber);
}
```

The method subtract is as follows:

```
int Number::subtract(Number inNumber) {
   return (this->data - inNumber.data);
}
```

The method *Number::subtract* functions as follows: So let's say we have 2 instances of **Number**, *foo* and *bar*, both have been initialized properly and have their respective data.
If I do

```
foo.subtract(bar);
```

The program does

```
return (foo.data - bar.data)
```

Now if I were to document *Number::subtract*, I could refer to bar as "the entered Number". But how exactly do I refer to foo?

"*this* Number" as in "The function returns the subtracts the entered Number from *this* Number"   doesn't sound quite right. Neither does "the *main* Number". I'm not sure what the exact term is.

Comment: When you are describing a binary operator, it's common to refer to either the "first and second" term/parameter, or the "left and right". Side-note, you probably don't want to pass `Number` instances by value. Even though this is a toy example containing integers, it's not best practice. Pass a const reference. If your method never operates on `this`, it might be better as a static method. You don't need to use `this->` to disambiguate `data` when there is _no_ ambiguity. It's overly verbose. Don't use "the entered number" to describe data used by a general purpose function.

Comment: Further notes: if `subtract` operates on two `Number` objects, consider making it return a `Number` instead of `int`. The function should be `const` if it does not modify the object. If you want to use `Number` and `int` interchangeably, you might want to consider some conversion operators. Speaking of operators, why not overload `operator-` instead of writing a `subtract` function? You hardly need to document that, since subtraction is pretty ubiquitously understood.

Comment: Personally, I don't see the point of the `subtract()` member function at all.   I'd provide an `operator-()` which returns the result of subtracting its right operand from its left operand.

Comment: I would define `operator-` as `friend` none-member binary function with `left` and `right` operands. I would also define the in-place subtract member operator (`operator-=`) AKA subtract-assign.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do it this way, you would want to do documentation like:

```
/**
 * @return The passed number subtracted from this number.
 */
```

You would also want to make this a constant function to make it clear that it doesn't affect any class members.

An alternative way you could do this is by using C++ custom operators. If you name the function `operator-`, then the following code will be the same:

```
foo.operator-(bar);
foo - bar;
```

For more information on this alternative, please reference [this](https://codeproject.com/articles/31783/custom-user-defined-operators-in-c) article.